# Typing a function which type definition depends on input types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm seeing a bit of a strange situation with TypeScript. I have tried to create a minimum reproducible example so that it can be easily tested in the TypeScript Playground.

- There is a type called `BaseA` which can have a different structure depending on one of its type arguments.
- There is a type called `DFunction` which represents a function that receives objects of type `BaseA`.
- The `DFunction` should have a different return type depending on the type of `BaseA` that it receives.

```
type BaseA<P, Special=false> = {
    payload: P;
} & Special extends true ? {_special:true} : {};

type DFunction = {
    <A extends BaseA<any, false>>(a: A): A;
    <A extends BaseA<any, true>>(a: A): Promise<A>;
};

function test(
    d: DFunction,
    normalA: BaseA<{x:number}, false>,
    specialA: BaseA<{x:number}, true>
) {
    // Since we are passing a `specialA` to `d`, the return type should be a Promise.
    d(specialA).then(() => {});
}
```

[Playground URL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgQQDwAUA0UDKkDGAlnADYC8AZqUgHxRlQDeAUFG1GHCCQPZwAmALijoA3MwC%20UAGS4CxElAgAPYBAB2-BFGAAnAK7QA-EwD6CeaUF7DU4YwnjmoSFAAiAMX3r8wQj3V6JlZ2VGQlVQ0tWEQUVDh1EGwqEloaAAo4YWQASmzxdigwiLVNbXgkNASknQMIGgysqFzhdF0eAFtCJDCacUdmZgpvX39AtQRgdJC2IXcvHz8AzBmodR5dDtJkYQq4xmVBdX0OgCMIXQlk6nqVwosIIm3d2LQDo5Pzy%20wbeuYc4KFAD0QNwhB80AA7tA4LpoJwEAhwQBzKBwKAAAweTxIyAxOh4mP4GJ%20AAtoHDgPpdONwNAEKSePoSPwoOc0SJ2l0kAA6Vb8dLYhS5HnAcnqdLpAFkOgOHL9IA)

This code errors on the last line since TypeScript doesn't understand that `d(specialA)` returns a Promise. How could I type `DFunction` in such a way that would make its return type depend on its input type?

One thing I'd like to note is that this pattern does work for simpler examples:

```
type DFunction = {
    <A extends string>(a: A): A;
    <A extends number>(a: A): Promise<A>;
};

function test(
    d: DFunction
) {
    d(5).then(() => {}); // no errors
    const b = d("5"); // `b` is inferred to be of type `string`
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because `BaseA<P, true>` is a subtype of `BaseA<P, false>`, and because the overload signature accepting the supertype appears before the one accepting the subtype. When two different overload signatures are both applicable, Typescript will not choose the "most specific" one; it will simply choose the first one it finds.

So there are two solutions: you can change the order of the overload signatures like so,

```
type DFunction = {
    <A extends BaseA<any, true>>(a: A): Promise<A>;
    <A extends BaseA<any, false>>(a: A): A;
};
```

Or you can change the definition of `BaseA` so that `BaseA<P, true>` is not assignable to `BaseA<P, false>`, like so:

```
type BaseA<P, Special=false> = {
    payload: P;
} & (Special extends true ? {_special: true} : {_special?: undefined});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgQQDwAUA0UDKkDGAlnADYC8AZqUgHxRlQDeAUFG1GHCCQPZwAmALijoA3MwC+UAGRQAFHghFSUCAA9gEAHb8EUYACcArtAD8TAPoICxEsMMmpwxlZulTwozogVCWiPwSAJTizKCQUAAiAGJe+MCEPFr0TKzsqMiqGtq6sIgoqHBaINgOEDQ0cnDCyEHC6AY8ALaESBk04uxQGVmaOnrwSGhFJVBUJLSV1VC1NeISoRRxCUn6EAjAcmlsQlGxWvGJWpjbUFo8Bk2kyMKDBYxqglpGTQBGEAYS2OO0J13WSlsNzyQ1QDyeL3en1KxnKzCCqS6AHokWcLlcSJkAO4XADWekQWQImn4p34cnOl2uQQAdJxuHx+DS1J12CjcH58NAsdA4AZoJwEAg-ABzKBwKAAAwBykxkv0PCl-ElpQAFtB+cAjAZkuFoAhVTwjCR+FB3uKRI0WkgaWS5DKgbTgOqtHI5AiyHRGMF5swgA)